# How to find how many words are in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make something to let you choose a bot's WPM in a type racing game so let's say you have a sentence like

```
for car owners, transmission failure can be a complete nightmare, costing thousands of dollars to fix or replace.
```

I need to find out how many words there are in it and the words can include periods and comma's like

```
for,
```

the comma can be included in the one word so that is just one word. And I need it to be able to read this sentence from a .txt file and give me the word count so I can calculate the delay needed to get the desired WPM. I have no idea how to do that so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `len(s.split(' '))`?  Where `s` is the string.

Comment: the space parmeter isnt needed since it does by spaces by default but great point that you can split by other stuff as well!

Comment: I would say split the whole string with space and that will give you an array and you can easily get the length of an array of strings(count of words).

Comment: It took you a lot more time and effort to write this question than it would have to Google "split text into words Python", which would have given you the answer, or something concrete to ask about. Please make a bit of an effort before asking.

Comment: `wc /path/to/file`

Comment: that's right @John D

Comment: @JohnD - Yes, space is default.  I included the space as it’s often useful to explicitly show the char on which the string is being split.  But yes, I do agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by @S3DEV:

Once you have read the text file into a string `s`, you can do `len(s.split())` to find the amount of words!